What HTML code can I use to autoplay a CANVA embedded on squarespace? (or is there any other way to do this?)
I've successfully embedded a CANVA on my squarespace website... but I want it to autoplay and move from slide to slide every 4 seconds automatically
Is there any ways to make this happen?
This is the embedded code I received from CANVA without the <>
div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 0; padding-top: 56.2500%;
padding-bottom: 0; box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(63,69,81,0.16); margin-top: 1.6em; margin-bottom: 0.9em; overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 8px; will-change: transform;"
iframe loading="lazy" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; border: none; padding: 0;margin: 0;"
src="https://www.canva.com/design/DAGGW4T4Km4/Y_rB641tYpwDrqJE_7afJg/view?embed" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" allow="fullscreen"
/iframe
/div
a href="https://www.canva.com/design/DAGGW4T4Km4/Y_rB641tYpwDrqJE_7afJg/view?utm_content=DAGGW4T4Km4&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=embeds&utm_source=link" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Mercy’s Kitchen</a
